# Html email ignores all the inline css

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I am posting the  content from html to php via ajax call. I want to send a html email     with that posted content. I echoed the posted data it has all the inline css. But in the mail I can see only the html content with no css effect.

my html code will have some static content with content editable features.

```
           <form id="form"name="form" method="post" action="xyz.php"  onsubmit="this.divcontent.value =    document.getElementById('email_body').innerHTML;">
           <input type="hidden" name="divcontent" id="divcontent" value="" />
           <div id="email_body" class="field" role="textbox" contenteditable="true">
           <div style="....">......</div>
           <a>.....</a>
           <div style="....">....</div>
           <div style="....">....</div>
           </div>
           <div class="send_mail"><button type="submit">Send</button></div>
           </form>
```

my ajax call

```
             $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : $("#form").attr('action'),
                        data : fields,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success: function() {......}....});
```

my php code is  sending the mail with no css effect.

```
        <?
            $email_body = $_POST[divcontent];
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";




                        //create email headers
                        $headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
                        'Reply-To: '.$emailid_from."\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers); 
               $array = array('error' => false, 'message' => $message);
               echo json_encode($array);
              echo json_encode($array);
    ?>


any suggestions?
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any inline CSS here, can you show where it should be?

Comment: @Pekka웃 `<div style="....">....</div>`

Comment: ok, but I'd like to see the actual styles

Comment: I am just using basic styles like colors and font-size.

Comment: are you viewing this in a webmail client or something? many will not allow css.

Comment: same html code with styles $email_body = '<div style="">....<div style="">....</div></div>' instead of $email_body = $_POST[divcontent]; works perfectly.

Comment: $email_body = stripslashes($_POST[divcontent]); solved my problem. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$email_body = stripslashes($_POST[divcontent]); solved my problem. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

When you are styling a newsletter, it's better to wrap your text in a font tag. E-mail clients are very very very picky about their parsing. You should code like it's 1990 (with tables).

```
<font face="verdana" color="green">This is some text!</font>
```

Font-tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Answer (score 1):

A lot of inline styles are removed from e-mail clients (both desktop and web-based) due to security, rendering, or advertising issues. Your inline-styles on `<div>` tags will most likely be stripped. Current best practices say to use `<p>` tags instead for `font-size` and `color` styles.

For more details, check out the [CSS Support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and [E-mail Design Guidelines](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/) on Campaign Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the css inline, like this:

> ```
> <div style="width:300px; margin: 10;">Content!</div>
>
> <font style="font-size:14px">Text</font>
> ```